# symfony3 datetime string in json object

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, datetime-format

My apologies in advance, if this has been answered before, I couldn't find the answer.
And also, i thought i fixed it, but it got unfixed for no appearant reason.
I have this code:

```
$date = new \DateTime('now');
$dateFormatted = $date->format(\DateTime::ISO8601);
$body->setDate($dateFormatted);
```

this should give me the current date and time in a string format, right?
after this, i pass the string to a json object, serialize it, and store it in the database (this works).
However, for some reason, the datetime object isn't formatted anymore, and is stored in an array like this:

```
{\"timezone\":{\"name\":\"+01:00\",\"transitions\":false,\"location\":false},\"offset\":3600,\"timestamp\":1518626336}
```

This breaks the rest of my functionality, as i want to store it in an object, and recreate a datetime object from it, whenever i fetch it again. I am clueless as to why this is happening. I am clearly formatting it to a string, or am i doing anything wrong? I've also tried clearing the cache, but that didn't do anything.

[EDIT] I've got a lot of answers from people telling me how to serialize an object to json format, this is not what i am looking for (as specified in my post). This is an example of a json serialized object containing a datetime array in my database, instead of a datetime string: (it is basically a message with a type, date, targetdate and messagetext)

```
"{\"type\":0,\"date\":{\"timezone\":{\"name\":\"+00:00\",\"transitions\":false,\"location\":false},\"offset\":0,\"timestamp\":1518638298},\"targetDate\":{\"timezone\":{\"name\":\"+01:00\",\"transitions\":false,\"location\":false},\"offset\":3600,\"timestamp\":1518638280},\"status\":0,\"messageText\":null}"
```

What I am trying to achieve with $dateFormatted = $date->format(\DateTime::ISO8601); is a string, that i can store in that object.
but what i am getting is an array.
i'm beginning to think that the ->format() functionality is broken.

Comment: It seems like you are setting some other object instead of $dateFormatted in $body->setDate somewhere. A json encoded \DateTime object looks different from your sample too.

Comment: that's what i thought too, and i checked and doublechecked. and i'm not encoding a datetime object, i'm encoding a json object which holds a formatted datetime object as a string. only, it's not formatted...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about how you are serializing the DateTime Object.

when you serialize the DateTime Object it can become like this only.

what you need to do is when you fetch the data from the database, you need to unserialize it, There you will get a DateTime Object

```
json_encode(new DateTime('@1419237113'));// serialize

json_decode(/*fetch data from db*/);// unserialize
```

Comment: i'm not serializing the datetime object, i'm storing the datetime as a string in an object, and then serialize that object. problem is, that because the format() doesn't actually format it as a string,  the datetime constructor will give an error saying that it expects a string, rather than an object, when i try to get that value back.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use ***PHP Serialize*** method is you want to store an `Object` in database.

You must **[serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)** the DateTime object (`$date = new \DateTime('now');`) before saving it in the database.

**Example:**

```
$date = new \DateTime('now');
$serialized_date = serialize($date);
```

$serialized_date can be stored as **String**.

Then when you retrieve the serialized DateTime, you can format the DateTime as you want. Before formatting you must **[unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)** the retrieved **String**.

**Example:**

```
$unserialized_date = unserialize($serialized_date);
echo $unserialized_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $unserialized_date->format(\DateTime::ISO8601);
```

Comment: I am using the symfony serializer component to serialize an object which holds a datetime string. first i format the datetime object with ->format(), then i put it in the object, and serialize the object. but the formatting doesn't work. the serialization is fine, so is the unserialization.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have answered my own question. Instead of passing the formatted DateTime object to my setter, i formatted it in my setter itself. for some reason this works... after that, when i want to get it back out. i make sure to pass it out as a string, rather than a datetime object. I don't know why, but using format, serialize, or normalize outside my getter does nothing and passes an array to the setter.